# How to remove notification from status bar when user click on it in android?

Tags: service, notifications

here in my case i implemented notification with service and i started notification like

```
 notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);  
 startForeground(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
```

and the flag

```
 myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

doesnt works in my case but if i remove

```
       startForeground(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
```

it works fine so when user click on notification, notification cancel automatically as flag works but in this case i am unable to stop service if user want???

Answer (score 0):

after some research i finally found solution. what i was doing wrong is, i was using startForeground(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification); though i am not updating ui. i call Context.stopservice(stopServiceIntent) from activity where i wish to stop service. and onDestroy section of Service, i cancel timer making timer null if not null and stop service by calling stopSelf();